# Setting Environmental variable issue

Tags: python, authentication, google-speech-api

I'm getting an auth error with my google api test, the code to set the environmental variable works alone, however when used in conjunction with the google test code the auth fails. I was also able to get the test code to work by running an `EXPORT` command in shell. For convenience, I'd like to be able to set the auth in my scripts.

```
 #This program will test the google speech api
 #while setting the environmental variable for the
 #authentication .json file and then authenticating

 import os

 # Imports the Google Cloud client library
 from google.cloud import language
 from google.cloud.language import enums
 from google.cloud.language import types

 # My code sets the authentication env variable
 os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = str('home/kyle/Security/test.json')

 # Instantiates a client
 client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

 # The text to analyze
 text = u'Hello, world!'
 document = types.Document(
     content=text,
     type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

 # Detects the sentiment of the text
 sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment

 print('Text: {}'.format(text))
 print('Sentiment: {}, {}'.format(sentiment.score, sentiment.magnitude))
```

The error:

```
   File "/home/kyle/python projects/googleSpeech/test/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 142, in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
os.environ[environment_vars.CREDENTIALS])
   File "/home/kyle/python projects/googleSpeech/test/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 67, in _load_credentials_from_file
'File {} was not found.'.format(filename))
 google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File home/kyle/Security/test.json was not found.
```

EDIT now exporting the json file doesnt work I ran this code to test reading the .json file

```
 fd = open(‘/home/kyle/Security/test.json’)
 dat = fd.read()
 fd.close()
```

Result:

```
 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file testRead.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Comment: The error says - "File home/kyle/Security/test.json was not found." Can you check if that file exists? Also, if it does, check the permissions.

Comment: the file does exist and when I print out the the environment variable it shows up 

Ill set its permission to 777 and see what happens

Comment: Set at 777 it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue required me to regenerate a new json key from the api console with the project owner permissions its working now no code change required

Comment: That solved my problem. This wa very confusing and misguiding error, and hard to find where that project admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this more closely, I think it might be this line:

> os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] =
>   str('home/kyle/Security/test.json')

Add a / in front of home/kyle/.... so that it is /home/kyle/...

Comment: interesting still not working and oddly I rebooted and ran the export commands now its just not working